# Where can I test programming tokens?

Tags: wallets, tokens, encoding

When I follow the instructions on ethereum.org I need to download the wallet and sync it again by downloading all the blocks. This takes hours everytime, I feel I'm missing out on something. Is there another way to code tokens and check how I can write my code or is the wallet the only way and will I have to wait for all the blocks to be downloaded everytime? I tried going to wallet.ethereum.org in my browser but I get a pop up saying:

Unable to connect. Please start geth with the following options:

geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "https://wallet.ethereum.org"

Optional add: --unlock .

I am stupid, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to try programming you can use the simulated network in the https://remix.ethereum.org/. It is a simulated network most things will work but to test some thing you will need a real network.

When you want to try to access a real network like mainnet or testnet you can use a public access node like those of https://www.infura.io/. They provide a good service, but some operations are not enabled.

Synchronizing requires a good computer at least 8Gb, a SSD with about 100 Gb free, and a good internet connection. In 'fast' mode it should be able to sync pretty quickly less than a day. If you do not have the required hardware you can use vps.

Comment: Thank you Ismael, how do I enable or ensure I'm using fast mode? I feel synchronizing used to be alot faster. It used to take less then 12 hours for over 1.000.000 blocks, now it takes 24 hours for 10.000 blocks.

Comment: By default geth start in fast mode, I use `geth --testnet --syncmode=fast --datadir=data console` to sync ropsten testnet. For synchronization a SSD is fundamental.